# Google sheets Import Range

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, importrange

I don't think that `importrange` is a real formula I have spent hours on this and it doesn't work full stop.

The sheet name of the data I wish to import is Fire Safety Audit but it was originally sheet 1

```
=importrange(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18B8KclREhEvOm9ZeOEEfpFSkTol1uxwlCt8kVfptO6I/edit#gid=2093530965";"fire safety audit"!A1:w1000")

=importrange(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18B8KclREhEvOm9ZeOEEfpFSkTol1uxwlCt8kVfptO6I/edit#gid=2093530965";"sheet1"!A1:w1000")
```

I have tried so many different types of formulas with colons, commas and semi colons.

Every time no matter what I try the number 2093530965 remains in blue font and it says I have parse error. Not quite sure why Google make this so complicated and do not have any help for it whatsoever. In summary its crap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the formula with the syntax in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en):

> Syntax
>   IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)

So, if your Sheet is named `Sheet1` change from this:

```
=importrange(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18B8KclREhEvOm9ZeOEEfpFSkTol1uxwlCt8kVfptO6I/edit#gid=2093530965";"sheet1"!A1:w1000")
```

To this:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18B8KclREhEvOm9ZeOEEfpFSkTol1uxwlCt8kVfptO6I/edit#gid=2093530965";"sheet1!A1:w1000")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use importrange literally everyday for work, it definitely is a real formula ;) that said your main issue from those examples is that you are missing a " infront of your url, google sheets formulas are also command delimited not semi colon as in open office. Finally, you're entire sheet and cell reference needs to be in 1 set of quotes.

Example -

```js
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SOMEID","SheetName!A:Z")
```

Once you have done that you are going to get a permissions error because you need permission to import data (even if you own both sheets). To fix this, hover over the cell with the error and click "Grant Access".